# Clarification on optimization problem

Tags: optimization

While reading a combinatorics paper about packing densities in compositions, I encountered the following optimization problem.

> Maximize 
>   $$f(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_5) = \sum_{1 \le i < j < k \le 5} \alpha_i \alpha_j \alpha_k$$
>   with the constraints
>   $$0 \le \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_5 \le 1, \quad\sum_{i=1}^5i\alpha_i=1$$

(See below for written out expressions.)

The authors conclude that $\alpha_5 = 0$ for the optimum with the following motivation:

> Differentiation yields no interior extreme points, so we conclude $\alpha_5 = 0$ for the optimum.

**Question:** Could someone elaborate a bit on what the authors are referring to and how they apply it in this specific problem? Is this related to linear programming? Polytope theory?

---

The function written out:

$$\begin{align}f(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4, \alpha_5)=&\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3 + \alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_4 + \alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_5 + \\
&\alpha_1\alpha_3\alpha_4 + \alpha_1\alpha_3\alpha_5 + \alpha_1\alpha_4\alpha_5 + \\
&\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4 + \alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_5 + \alpha_2\alpha_4\alpha_5 + \\ 
&\alpha_3\alpha_4\alpha_5
\end{align}$$

And the constraints: 
$$\alpha_1+2\alpha_2+3\alpha_3+4\alpha_4+5\alpha_5=1$$
$$0 \le \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_5 \le 1$$

---

EDIT: Please note that the question is not how to solve the complete optimization problem. This can be done with Lagrange multipliers, or possibly other techniques, about which <s>I will probably ask a question later on</s>I have posted a [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884654/clarification-on-optimization-problem-continued), once the fact that $\alpha_5 = 0$ is established (and, at least numerically, even before that). **The question is what techniques the authors use, and how they use them, to conclude $\alpha_5 = 0$.**

Comment: Your problem is a cubic optimization problem. Unfortunatelly, the literature about cubic problems is scarce. In my opinion, your problem is not related to linear programming.

Comment: I think for any $\alpha_k$, the objective function is linear. Given that the constraint is also linear, the optimum lies in some corner point. Since $\alpha_5=1$ violates the constraint, so $\alpha_5=0$.

Comment: "for any $\alpha_k$, the objective function is linear." This doesn't matter. Your argument applies only if the constraint is linear in all variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence you have quoted *is wrong*. That is an error in their paper. Fortunately, it looks like Innuo's answer looks correct, so they happened upon the truth anyway.

Let me explain what they are *trying* to do. Consider the problem\begin{array}{ll}\text{minimize} & f(x) \\ \text{subject to} & x\in C\end{array}where $C$ is a closed, bounded, connected set, and $f$ is differentiable on $\mathop{\textrm{int}} C$, the interior of $C$.

If we can find a point $\bar{x}\in\mathop{\textrm{int}} C$ satisfying $\nabla f(\bar{x})=0$, then $\bar{x}$ is a *candidate* solution to the constrained problem. Of course, we'll usually need some additional conditions too (for instance, $f$ is convex) before we can be sure it is a global optimum, but at least it's a candidate. For example, consider the problem $$\begin{array}{ll}\text{minimize} & f(x)=x^2\\\text{subject to}&-1\leq x\leq 1\end{array}$$In this case, $\nabla f(\bar{x})=0$ at $\bar{x}=0$, which is on the interior of the feasible region $C=[-1,1]$. $f$ is convex, so $\bar{x}$ is the global minimum of $f$, and also the solution to the constrained problem.

On the other hand, if $\nabla f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in\mathop{\textrm{int}} C$, then it *must* be the case that the solution to the problem is on the boundary of $C$. It's a simple logical argument: there are no candidates on $\mathop{\textrm{int}} C$, so the solution must be on $x\in C-\mathop{\textrm{int}} C=\mathop{\textrm{bd}} C$. We need no other conditions to draw this conclusion. So, for example, consider the problem $$\begin{array}{ll}\text{minimize} & f(x)=x^2\\\text{subject to}&1\leq x\leq 2\end{array}$$Now $\bar{x}=0$ is *outside* of $\mathop{\textrm{int}} C=(1,2)$, so the solution *must* lie on the boundary $\mathop{\textrm{bd}}C=\{1,2\}$. We can easily verify that $x=1$ is the solution in this case.

That's what the authors of this paper are going for here. *Unfortuantely, they have made a mistake*. The feasible region is
$$C=\big\{(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4,\alpha_5)\,\big|\,0\leq \alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4,\alpha_5\leq 1,\,\textstyle\sum_i i\alpha_i=1\big\}$$
This feasible region *has an empty interior*---that is, $\mathop{\textrm{int}}C=\emptyset$! So of *course* the solution must lie on the boundary of the feasible region, because $\mathop{\textrm{bd}} C\equiv C$. It's tautological, and not very helpful. In particular, it does *not* follow from this that $\alpha_5\in\{0,1\}$, because there are plenty of points satisfying $0<\alpha_5<1$ on the boundary of $C$.

Perhaps they were thinking about the *relative interior*, which is
$$\mathop{\textrm{relint}} C=\big\{(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4,\alpha_5)\,\big|\,0<\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4,\alpha_5<1,\,\textstyle\sum_i i\alpha_i=1\big\}$$
But the derivative test I describe above, and which they applied in their paper, *cannot be applied* without modification to the relative interior. It only applies to the *true* interior of $C$.

One way to "save" the derivative test here is to eliminate the equality constraint and a single variable, say $\alpha_5$. If we do this, then we get the new objective
$$\begin{aligned} f(x) &= \alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3+\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_4+\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4\\&\qquad+\tfrac{1}{5}(\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_2\alpha_3+\alpha_3\alpha_4)(1-\alpha_1-2\alpha_2-3\alpha_3-4\alpha_4)\end{aligned}$$
And the feasible region becomes
$$C=\big\{(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4)\,\big|\,0\leq\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4\leq 1,\,0\leq 1-\alpha_1-2\alpha_2-3\alpha_3-4\alpha_4\leq 5\big\}$$
This feasible region has a non-empty interior, so the derivative test could be applied to this modified $f(x)$. Another way to save it would be to look at the equality-constrained problem
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} & \textstyle \sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq 5} \alpha_i\alpha_j\alpha_k \\
\text{subject to} & \textstyle \sum_i i \alpha_i = 1
\end{array}
and conclude that the Lagrangian of this problem
$$L(\alpha,\lambda ) = - \textstyle \sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq 5} \alpha_i\alpha_j\alpha_k - \lambda \left( \textstyle \sum_i i \alpha_i - 1 \right)$$
has no critical points satisfying $\nabla L(\alpha,\lambda)=0$ on the interior of the inequality constraints $$0<\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4,\alpha_4<1$$
I have no idea if that's feasible. But what I know you *can't* do is just look at $f(x)$ by itself.

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. I will need some time to digest it though, but the bounty is yours! :)

Comment: I wish you could have split the bounty somehow. I know that you were looking for more of an explanation of the author's thinking, so technically my answer is closer to what you asked for. But I think Innuo's answer is exactly the kind of insight the authors *should* have used! Regardless, thank you!

Comment: Oops, have a little min/max mixup in here. Fixing...

Answer (score 6):

Note that the constraints imply that $\alpha_4 \leq \frac{1}{4}$ and $\alpha_5 \leq \frac{1}{5}$ for any feasible point.

Now consider the objective value at a feasible point $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4, \alpha_5)$. If $\alpha_5 > 0$, then the objective is strictly larger at  the point $ (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4 + \frac{5 \alpha_5}{4}, 0)$, which can checked to be feasible also.

I don't see why the fact that the interior has no extremum even matters.

Comment: You've done the authors of this paper a favor: their confusion that $\alpha_5=0$ is right, as you have shown; but their reasoning is wrong!

Comment: I missed the fact that the interior is empty. Thanks for checking. I wonder if the authors gave a hand-wavy argument once they found that for all examples they tried $\alpha_5$ happened to be $0$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my guess. I mean, it's a common argument to make, that the solution is on the boundary of the feasible set. Kind of a formulaic thing to do, really. They just got sloppy.

Comment: Thanks Innuo, this is very helpful.